# Risk of swapping output reference parameter and local variable in C++

Tags: c++

A function has an output reference parameter to pass the result. Inside the function, it'd be cumbersome to reset some of the properties of the output parameter, so I want to create a new local object and initialize it in a simpler way. Then, to make it the output, I simply swap the reference of the parameter and my new local variable. Is there any risk or side effect of that?

For example, I have some function like this

```
void getOutput(int someInput, OutputType& out) {
    // Create a local OutputType variable
    OutputType localVar(someInput);

    // Fetch data from other functions and set the field in localVar
    localVar.someField = someFunction();

    // ... other processing
    localVar.someField2 = ...;

    // To avoid object assignment, swap the reference
    swap(localVar, out);
}
```

Comment: Depends: on class `OutputType` and the implementation details of `swap`.  With that said it's an ok way to do what you want to.

Comment: *"To avoid object assignment, swap the reference"* Swap will move-assign under the hood anyway. You can simply do `out = std::move(localVar);` instead.

Comment: But while you are at it, you might as well also do `localVar = std::move(out);` but then what is the point of making the local copy? There is no advantage in the sample code, you could just take a reference if you just dislike the name. But perhaps your program is reliant on the lifetime of `out`?

Comment: @GemTaylor The thing is, `out` could be some high dimensional matrix represented by `vector`s. I won't know the size of it until it fetches the data inside this function. Resizing may take a lot of work, but it is handy to just initialize a new matrix.

Comment: @hiimdaosui One of the advantages of using an output parameter like this could be reusing the existing memory block. Replacing it via move or swap removes this advantage.

Comment: Ok, I guess. I had misread that you were initialising from `someInput`, anyway. You could start with `out = OutputType();` to clear your output object. The other option is to *return* your object, and let the compiler choose between return value optimisation and move assignment.